# which is faster ,a variable or direct access of the cell value?

Tags: vba, excel

well I have lots of string manipulations like

```
1st one
ActiveSheet.Cells(i, "B").Value = Replace(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, "B").Value, ",", " ")
ActiveSheet.Cells(i, "B").Value = Replace(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, "B").Value, "/", " ")
ActiveSheet.Cells(i, "B").Value = Replace(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, "B").Value, "&", " ")
ActiveSheet.Cells(i, "B").Value = Replace(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, "B").Value, "(", " ")
2nd one
store=ActiveSheet.Cells(i, "B").Value
store= Replace(store, "/", " ")
store = Replace(store, "&", " ")
store = Replace(store, "(", " ")
```

and some trim operations and sometimes finding string length and sometimes comparison.

I have to do looping for cells 1 to 4000. The question is storing the cell value in string and accessing is better and faster? or writing the activesheet cell value in the macro is itself faster?

```
store = activesheet.cells(i,"B").value and use store everywhere 
or write activesheet.cells(i,"B").value everywhere?
```

Which is better which is more optimized  I was kinda thinking if we mention the cell value it has to go to sheet and get it back but if we store it in variable then it might be faster. I just need to know which is better ?

Comment: If you aren't sure if the sentences include those 3 items, although it's more lines of codes, it's faster to do a check using instr to see if the character exists before doing replace. Even when replacing nothing, replace is a very cost-heavy action to do.

Comment: If you are doing a lot of string manipulation then it would be worth having a look into Regular Expressions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Accessing Excel is slow. Storing things you'll access more than twice in a variable will always be faster, and dumping a range of cells (one call to Excel) into a variant array is even better.

Remember, Excel and VBA are not the same. It's like two guys in the same flat but different rooms. Everytime you access Excel, VBA has to knock on Excel's door.

**Update**:
The above is general advice for all code. Concerning the particular code above and what you are doing, it might actually be faster to use Excel's search and replace functionality on the range like so:

```
Sub test()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With Range("B1:B4000")
    .Replace what:="(", replacement:=" ", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
    :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

    .Replace what:="&", replacement:=" ", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
    :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

    .Replace what:="/", replacement:=" ", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
    :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: In addition to what Issun said, the number of "dots" also influences speed. And I would go even further by saying that if you access something more than _once_ you should create a variable instead.

Comment: +1 for the suggestion of getting the range at once ! much faster.

Comment: +1 Nice explanation.  However in the situation posted above I would use the With/End With block. In your example niko definitely use either With or a variable BUT on the flip side variables can often be over used and unnecessary.

Comment: Reafidy, you're right. The question he asked didn't quite apply to the code in the example. I've added a sample of how this particular code can be done using Excel functionality, which in this case would be pretty darn fast.

Comment: As a variant array fan myself, I think its worth pointing out that when working with variant arrays of unknown size then the range should be tested to see if holds at least two cells - as the variant array approach will raise errors on single cells

Comment: Very good point to add. I think most of us found it out the hard way when we started working with variant arrays. :p

Comment: yes  i skip the variant way as it looks so confusing but my manager tells me to do with variant arrays thats why i always ask you for a faster performance!

Comment: At least as confusing as variant arrays may be, you get great performance out of them, making it well worth your trouble. :)